# how to find namespace of dll at runtime

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Namespace of an Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653128/how-to-get-namespace-of-an-assembly)

when i load a assembly how can i find its namespace suppose if i load a exam.dll how can i find its namespace

Comment: Google landed me here looking for a related question - get all types in a namespace via Reflection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79693/getting-all-types-in-a-namespace-via-reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, an assembly can contain many namespaces.  It's often that 1 assembly == 1 namespace, but this is not required at all.

To find the namespaces in the assembly, just get all of the types in the assembly. See [Assembly.GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) for details as to how to do this.

From the type, you have the fully qualified type name, and the namespace of the type.