# Why does GetManifestResourceStream returns null (with dotnet core)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, reflection, .net-assembly

Using dotnet core:  .NET Core SDK Version: 3.1.102

Why is the following returning null 
?

```
typeof(MyClassName).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyFile.cs")
```

I verified the file exists in solution and has build action in properties '**Embedded Resource**'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check what resource names are available:

```
string[] names = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

And then if Resource exists write correct name of Resource

Comment: ok - so I did this - and _names_ does Not contain the name I am interested in - so what can I do now ?

Comment: Even when I try to use one of the **existing** names from the names list I get null - any ideas ?

Comment: @Danielle Have you tried to set build action of that file to `Embedded Resource`?

Comment: @Danielle [maybe this is a reason why `.cs` file cannot be seen as ResourceFile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27851799/1646240)

Comment: ok - can't explain this - but - one of the names in names list is actually the **first** class in the file that I am looking for  ("MyFile.cs") - and using this class name **instead** of of the file name actually works

Comment: @RicardoPeres, how does that explain the behavior where the `ResourceNames` outputs the classes present in `MyFile.cs`, can you explain ?

Comment: @Clint: I would, but I doubt that you would understand. I tested and it works *exactly* as I said, and it can be easily proved.

Comment: @RicardoPeres, what can I do to replicate it ?, I tried manually changing the namespace, but `GetResourceNames` still retrieves the FullyQualifiedName, I would appreciate it if you can explain how

Comment: All I wrote in project ConsoleApplication1 was:
var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("ClassLibrary1");
var names = asm.GetManifestResourceNames();
var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("ClassLibrary1.Class1.cs");
Class1.cs was marked as embedded resource in project ClassLibrary1. Didn't change anything else. That's all.

Comment: @RicardoPeres, yea I know, but its still unclear as to what is causing the `GetManifestResourceNames()` to print out the classes present within the embedded resource in your example (Class1.cs). and what do you mean by "root namespace" I think its a wrong notion

Comment: I don't believe that is happening. I can share a sample project. Root namespace is the official name.

Comment: @RicardoPeres I think what you intend by root namespace is "DefaultNameSpace" [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96317/how-do-you-get-the-root-namespace-of-an-assembly) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885888/how-get-the-default-namespace-of-project-csproj-vs-2008), and the link about conventions you shared earlier (about VB.Net and C#) does not really apply in our scenario.
Yea it's really unbelievable that `GetManifestResourceNames()`prints out the classes present within the embedded resource, this can't happen even with a conflict in the namespace.
Cheers, good discussion !!

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.localization.rootnamespaceattribute.rootnamespace. Root namespace is the official name and this is the official attribute to set it. Can also be set on the .csproj through the <RootNamespace> property.

Answer (score 3):

Just an update to .**NET 5**. What helped me to find out the name of the resources to help fix my issue in **.NET 5** was the following:

```
string[] names = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();

                foreach (var name in names)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(name);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of the file must include the "root namespace" of the assembly, for example, "My.Namespace.MyFile.cs". Is is typically the name of the assembly, but it can be changed on the .csproj file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but what really made me understand what is going on was printing out the names list - as suggested in the selected answer :)  because the file name that I was using was already **with** the root namespace as you pointed out here, so just that didn't help me much

Answer (score 1):

Load the *assembly* where the *resource* is embedded, iterate through the `GetManifestResourceNames` to find the Fully Qualified Resource name which is then used to *GetManifestResourceStream*.

You can try

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MainWindow)).Location);
string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(names[0]);
```

Comment: This approach is already explained in another answer and doesn't work for OP