# Is there a good pattern for naïve assembly initialization?

Tags: c#, .net

Say we have several assemblies, and they all implement IAnimal, and we'd like go to one place to find out about the presence of the other IAnimal implementation.

features:

- we don't want pre-knowledge outside of an assembly
- there could be a register class / method within the assembly
- it is preferable *not* to use reflection.  So far this seems to be the only way though

discussion:

I imagined doing this statically via inheritance, however, I'm not aware of an assembly level initialization sequence.

Comment: Discovering types dynamically at execution time is practically the *definition* of reflection... I can't imagine any other way of doing it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: No answers are good.  Maybe I can live with an [IAmAIAnimalRegistrar] attribute.  Now to think about efficient discovery via LINQ.  Via convention?  Is it not possible (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96317/how-do-you-get-the-root-namespace-of-an-assembly).  Ahh.  Could define the same Registration namespace in each assembly.  That might work.

Comment: All of these things are going to require reflection sooner or later...

Comment: Implement a factory in that assembly.  The assembly itself has no trouble knowing what classes implement an interface.

Comment: I've got a kind of Factory proxy going on.  Still need to be able to find each factory in a naive way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting your app you could register to the AssemblyLoad of your AppDomain:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += new AssemblyLoadEventHandler(NewAssemblyLoaded);
```

and define NewAssemblyLoad to add the IAnimal implementations to a list of Types (e.g. animalTypes) you maintain:

```
static void NewAssemblyLoaded(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
{
    Assembly anAss = args.LoadedAssembly;
    foreach (Type t in Assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (!t.IsInterface && typeof(IAnimal).IsAssignableFrom(t))
            animalsList.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat touch.  Is this a way to be naive about what is loaded and when?

Comment: Yes, you just have to be sure that the assemblies containing IAnimal implementation are loaded after the subscription to the event (and of course you shouldn't change your AppDomain)

Comment: 'just'.  Sounds like I'd need two approaches -- subscribe + scan all now.  Is there a way to guarantee assembly load order?

Comment: If you put the event subscription as the first instruction of your Main method everything should work just fine

Answer (score 6):

I suggest taking a look at [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/). It is practically designed for this kind of thing.

It does use reflection, as this is the mechanism created for such dynamic discovery. I doubt you will find a solution that doesn't use some level of reflection.

Comment: I did look at this a while back.  It's probably over the top for now.  It appears that even MEF still uses meta data though.

Answer (score 1):

I've written [an extension method](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrsteve/archive/2011/03/23/findingtypesinlocallydeployedassemblies2.aspx) which allows you to look up deployed Types which match certain criteria at runtime - it does use Reflection, but you may find it useful.

```
IEnumerable<Type> animalTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetAvailableTypes(
        typeFilter: t => !t.IsInterface && typeof(IAnimal).IsAssignableFrom(t));
```